# Cant select location or pricing tier in FormRecognizer Preview

Tags: azure, preview, azure-cognitive-services

I registered for the Preview of Azure Cognitive Services FormRecognizer. I received the confirmation E-Mail today and wanted to try the FormRecognizer Tutorial on my subscription. Unfortunately, I am not able to create the FormRecognizer resource since the DropDowns "Location" and "Pricing Tier" are empty / no selectable values but are mandatory fields.

I already tried other browsers (Chrome, IE, Edge) also after deleting the Cache of the browsers.

Expected result would be, that I can chose a location and a pricing tier for the FormRecognizer preview resource.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are logged in to the Azure Portal using the Azure account associated with the white-listed subscription.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I actually did sign in with the Account associated with the subscription I sent in the initial registraion form. 
@Neta, I will send you an E-Mail with my details, so maybe we can figure this out together.

Comment: Christoph, were you able to get this working? We are having the same problem over in our office.  I am assuming it is taking a little longer to get white-listed, but I'm not certain of that.

Comment: georryan, are you logged in into the Azure Portal associated with the Azure subscription ID provided in the access request form ?

Comment: I was.  Although it started working for me earlier today, so it must have just been a timing issue.  Thanks @Neta.

Comment: Have the same problem.  Only have one azure registered email and tried all the subscriptions, none worked. Its not confused between Work and Live accounts is it?

Comment: Is the Azure subscription ID in the portal when logged in the same one provided in the access request ?